# Selecting Plot for Locator

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, locator

Assume I have a manipulate with two graphics/plots as outputs. One of my parameters is a locator. How can I select in which of the plots the locator appears?

Let's say I have the output given by this:

```
Manipulate[{Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, p}], PlotRange -> 10, 
   Axes -> True], 
  Plot[p[[1]]*x + p[[2]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 50]}, {p, Locator}]
```

[image]

I want to change the locator from the graphic on the left to the plot on the right.

Here is a screenshot of the code running:

[image]

Comment: @rm-rf oops, I forgot about doing that. Thanks for bringing this to my attention. It failed on `12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`. Works fine for version `12.2` and higher.

Answer (score 3):

If you just remove the first Graphics expression, the Locator will show overlaid on the Plot.

```
Manipulate[Plot[p[[1]]*x + p[[2]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 50], {p, Locator}]
```

If you want to combine both graphical things into one, you can use Show.

```
Manipulate[
  Show[{Plot[p[[1]]*x + p[[2]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 50], 
    Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, p}], PlotRange -> 10, Axes -> True]}], 
  {p, Locator}]
```

If you want to keep two graphics things, one for manipulating the Locator but the other also showing the Locator, you could do something like this:

```
Manipulate[
  {Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, p}], PlotRange -> 10, Axes -> True], 
  Show[{Plot[p[[1]]*x + p[[2]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 50], 
    Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[p]}]}]}, 
  {p, Locator}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! What about just showing the locator on the plot and not on the graphics? Which is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @AndrésMorales, you can use a Locator as a Graphics object, and so you can combine a Locator with the Plot using Show. However, the Manipulate gets a bit confused if you just use Locator[p], I think because it's giving precedence to the first Graphics object. So, I used Locator[q] and inserted a q=p; elsewhere in the expression. But, having said all of that, you might want to just create a Dynamic expression rather than a Manipulate. I can try to show that, but can you describe what you want the final output to be? Two synchronized locators overlaid on two different graphical displays?

Comment: Thank you. I want the final output to be a graphic with one locator, and one graphic without a locator (but that uses the info from the locator for calculations). However, I do want to be able to control which graphic has the visual locator.

Answer (score 3):

You could use LocatorPane. Just make sure you wrap everything that needs to be dynamic in Dynamic. Here is a generic example that you can hopefully refine. (You might want the pt to be local, so look into Module or DynamicModule.)

```
pt = {0, 0};
Grid[{{
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
    Dynamic[Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, pt}], PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> 300]]], 
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
    Dynamic[Plot[pt[[1]]*x + pt[[2]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-50, 50}}, ImageSize -> 300]]]}}]
```

Comment: This shows the Locator in both parts, so, just modify to use one LocatorPane on whichever side you want and then a Dynamic[Graphics[...]] in the other (just strip off the LocatorPane).